# How to customize Allure report to add new status to allure status report?

Tags: java, java-8, testng, allure

I have allure report integrated with our testng automation framework. And, we are trying to get the allure reporting customized in such a way that we would be able to get the pass% for the Priority 1 test cases. 
At the moment, the allure report only contains the Failed, Broken, Canceled, Pending, and Passed test cases. Is there a way I can maybe add another category to the report say "P1 Tests"?

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature that lets you set a tests severity: 
https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_severity_3

I'm not aware of a way to show test status by severity in %. The "Graphs" category has a widget that comes close to it. It shows each test status in columns according to amount of tests. You can see how many tests failed, are brocken, etc for each level of severity.

There are 5 levels:

- blocker
- critical
- normal
- minor
- trivial

Example from the docs:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    @Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```